# why does web3 have 2 different account creation method

Tags: solidity, web3js, contract-design

I am trying to create an account in the blockchain for a new User who will be using my dapp.

I am using the web3 1.x version so it has a method `web3.eth.accounts.create()` 
which returns somehting like this :

```
{
    address: "0xb8CE9ab6943e0eCED004cDe8e3bBed6568B2Fa01",
    privateKey: "0x348ce564d427a3311b6536bbcff9390d69395b06ed6c486954e971d960fe8709",
    signTransaction: function(tx){...},
    sign: function(data){...},
    encrypt: function(password){...}
}
```

Also web3 has the method `web3.personal.newAccount()` which only returns an account address.

Now i want to know why there are two and what difference they have between each other ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`web3.personal.newAccount()` calls [`personal_newAccount`](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/wiki/Management-APIs#personal_newaccount) on your node

Taken from geth doc

> Generates a new private key and stores it in the key store directory. The key file is encrypted with the given passphrase. Returns the address of the new account.

`web3.eth.accounts.create()` generates the account data without communicating with an ethereum node. That's why it returns the private key , because there's no account manager to handle your accounts / keys

Comment: so the account created via `web3.eth.accounts.create()` is not a usuable account ? what did you mean about account manager.

Comment: Both accounts are usable. One is created inside the node web3 is talking to (geth / parity) the other account is returned to you but not managed by the node.

Comment: What do you exactly mean by "managed".

Comment: geth saves, encrypts, loads and unlocks the accounts for you. The are saved as files on your local filesystem. You don't need to know where they are because geth knows and manages interaction with your accounts.
With `web3.eth.accounts.create()` geth does not know about the account. It is your responsability to store, load and use the account generated

Comment: So, if i am right, if an account X is not managed by geth then running `web3.eth.accounts` won't return X.

Comment: That's correct, it won't be returned if not managed

Comment: thanks for the answer but how do i use and get the not managed account to be managed by a certain node ? is there anyway of getting the privatekey of a managed account created by web3 ?